# PHP: Compare 2 different array/object. Check if a field value exist in the other

Tags: php, arrays

I have an object/array like this:

```css
[LineItems] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (

                            [ProductNumber] => PAC-051-9716
                            [Description] => KIT CLOSURE 6" BUTT THRD BLK
                            [Cost] => 24.84
                            [ExtCost] => 24.84
                            [OrdNum] => X4146223

                        )

                )
```

And the other object/array looks like this:

```css
                    [0] => VendorBillItem Object
                        (   
                            [vendorName] => PAC-051-9716
                            [quantity] => 1
                            [rate] => 24.84
                            [amount] => 24.84
                        )
```

How can I check if [ProductNumber] field value from the first array exist in the 2nd array by checking it against [vendorName] field value?

Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: Please consider that both array may have multiple element counts. I just post 1 for each array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you build an index for 2nd array.

```
foreach ($vendorBills as $key => $vendorBill) {
  empty($index[$vendorBill->vendorName]) && $index[$vendorBill->vendorName] = array();
  $index[$vendorBill->vendorName][] = $key;
}
```

After that just check

```
!empty($index[$lineItem->ProductNumber])
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose two arrays are named as $lineitemsArray and $venderBillArray

```
foreach($lineitemsArray as $lineItem)
{
    foreach($venderBillArray as $vendorItem)
    {
        if($lineItem->ProductNumber==$vendorItem->vendorName)
        {

            echo "equal";

        }
        else{
            echo "not equal";
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the 2 arrays can both have multiple elements so I need to loop both arrays. I was looking for a fast and easy way to check if the ProductNumber exist in the 2nd array. Sorry for the confusion.